# Append line to the file without line break

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Right now i am appending new line to existing file like this:

```
   using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TemplateOutput))
   {
      sw.WriteLine(parsedFile);
   }
```

This way AppendText adds automatically a line break to the end of the line. How could i change that so it wouldnt add the line break to the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the [`WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx) call to [`Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx).

Alternatively, if you're just trying to append some text to a file, use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx):

```
File.AppendAllText(TemplateOutput, parsedFile);
```

No need to do any more work than that :)

Answer (score 5):

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TemplateOutput))
   {
      sw.Write(parsedFile);
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [StreamWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(TemplateOutput))
{      
sw.Write(parsedFile);   
}
```